# What should be the best data source for problem related to product that can measure the affluence in localities of metro cities in India?

Tags: cluster-analysis, data-science

You are tasked with an open-ended problem statement to develop a data product that can measure the affluence in localities of metro cities in India.
Choose the city that you are most comfortable with.

How would go about solving this problem?
Which data sources would you use?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming as defined in the guidelines.

Answer (score 2):

You would be looking for a data source which is:

- recent
- official (possible from the government of India)
- in a public format, or with a public API allowing you to query data,

The [censusindia "Population Enumeration Data" (Final Population)](http://www.censusindia.gov.in/2011census/population_enumeration.html) of 2011 is promising.
It has a [Population Finder 2011](http://www.censusindia.gov.in/pca/Searchdata.aspx) page, but also a [data.gov.in API page](https://data.gov.in/search/site?query=census), especially the [Town Amenities, Census 2011](https://data.gov.in/catalog/town-amenities-census-2011?filters%5Bfield_catalog_reference%5D=534941&format=json&offset=0&limit=6&sort%5Bcreated%5D=desc), which you can use/script.